# Setting colors of slices in highcharts piechart via jsx in React (passing data entries as array, not hash)

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts, reactjs

I am having trouble setting specific colors for each slice of a pie chart.  I am passing the data field as an array from a JSON file.  Here is an example of the data:

```
#JSON
[
  [
    "A",
    1,
    "#FFFFFF"
  ],
  [
    "B",
    2,
    "#A0F0F0"
  ],
  [
    "C",
    3,
    "#A0A0F0"
  ]
]
```

Here is what setting a slice color using the standard PieChart format looks like without JSX: http://jsfiddle.net/rxfuscvq/

In my case, PieChart recognizes that the first line in each array is the `name` field and the second line is the `y` field but it does not recognize that my third line is the `color` field.  I need to pass these values as an array, presumably because I am using PieCharts in a jsx wrapper: http://pastie.org/private/mhixvhkg1j5stgrflqlurg

Nonetheless, how can I get PieCharts to recognize that the third line is for the `color` field?

Edit: Please also see HighChartMixin which PieCharts uses to get HighCharts functionality: http://pastie.org/private/cj8zfsefg9w8u9minpt0ww

Comment: You don't show your mixin "HighChartMixin" in the pastebin which appears to contain all your actual react rendering code and how it actually renders the pie chart so no one can really help you without that.

Comment: Okay, here is `HighChartMixin`: http://pastie.org/private/cj8zfsefg9w8u9minpt0ww

Comment: Looks like there's still code missing here, `initializeChart` creates a chart instance and sets it to state but nowhere in your mixin or component do you do anything with `this.state.chartInstance`.  Returning false from `componentDidUpdate` does nothing, I think you mean `shouldComponentUpdate` instead if you're trying to stop it from updating.  Other than that I'd suggest you try `console.log(coe)` at line 34 of the mixin and see if your `series.data` object is how you'd expect it should be.

Comment: Also, when using the fiddle you provided for example charts, adding a colour as 3rd element in one of the series arrays does not change the colour so I'd suggest that highcharts doesn't recognise this and you want to be sending the series data over as objects instead using `{name: 'foo', y:  3, color: "#FFFFFF"}`.  This doesn't appear to be anything to do with JSX or React per-se.

Comment: @MikeDriver, the issue is that if I pass the data as objects, they aren't rendered at all.  Nothing is even processed by your suggested `console.log(coe)` statement in HighChartsMixin.  If I pass the data as arrays, I get them rendered, although your `console.log` statement shows the `color` line is ignored.  If the `JSON` input is `{
            "A",
            y: 1,
            color: "#F0F0F0"
          }` then the corresponding Javascript object in the console is `name: "A",visible: true,y: 1`